# How to define child stages in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript, panel, containers

This is not really a programming question, so please let me know if I should move it somewhere else.

I want to know if there is a way to define a -parent- object (like a Panel, or a Stage inside the main Stage) that contains various elements (like TextFields), so that I can Show/Hide the parent object, and all the contained elements will be affected?

So I'm asking C#'s Panel equivalent in AS3.

Thanks !

Comment: I found that the answer was "MovieClip"..

Answer (score 0):

In terms of classes that you can instantiate (ie, not abstract or base classes), you'll want either [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html) or [MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) (as noted in your comment) ... but note that MovieClip extends Sprite, so it's best to use a Sprite unless you have a special reason not to.  There is a good article on AS3 display-list programming [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Sprite that's the child of another Sprite object.  The hierarchy is unlimited.  If at any level of the heirarchy you do `visible = false`, all the child objects in the hierarchy will also not be displayed.  If you do `removeChild()` on an Sprite, all it's child objects will also be removed.  Same thing applies for matrix transformations.  You can of course, inherit from Sprite and continue the same pattern.